# mvvmcross N-06-Books Sample How to change Tableview size after loading?

Tags: uitableview, mvvmcross

Stuart's [N-06 Books sample](https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-06-Books/Books.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs) is good for getting basic understanding about using MvxSimpleTableViewSource.

```
[Register("FirstView")]
public class FirstView : MvxViewController
{
     public override void ViewDidLoad()
     {
          View = new UIView(){ BackgroundColor = UIColor.White};
          base.ViewDidLoad();

          // ios7 layout
          if (RespondsToSelector(new Selector("edgesForExtendedLayout")))
               EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;

          var textField = new UITextField(new RectangleF(10, 10, 300, 40));
          Add(textField);
          var tableView = new UITableView(new RectangleF(0, 50, 320, 500),  UITableViewStyle.Plain);
          Add(tableView);

          tableView.RowHeight = 88;
          var source = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource(tableView, BookCell.Key, BookCell.Key);
          tableView.Source = source;
          var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, Core.ViewModels.FirstViewModel>();
          set.Bind(textField).To(vm => vm.SearchTerm);
          set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.Results);
          set.Apply();
          tableView.ReloadData();
     }
}
```

But how can resize the tableview's height according it's content once it loads data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you want to do... Normally in an iOS UI, the tableview size is fixed regardless of its content.

However, if you did want to resize the table then you could:

1. Inherit from `MvxTableViewSource` or `UITableView` and provide some logic there
2. Or add a binding in your class to some View property `TableCount`, bind that property and then implement the sizing logic there. Something like:

   ```
      set.Bind(this).For(v => v.TableCount).To(vm => vm.Results.Count);


      private int _tableCount
      public int TableCount {
          get { return _tableCount; }
          set {
              // implement your sizing animations here (maybe animate constraints?)
          }
      }
   ```

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Stuart's answer, here is an example for the frame of the table:

```
int _tableHeight;

public int TableHeight
{
    get { return _tableHeight; }
    set
    {
        _tableHeight = value;

        _myPlayers.Frame = _tableHeight > 0 ? new CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, Dimens.TableRowHeight * _tableHeight) : new CGRect(0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, Dimens.TableRowHeight * BusinessConstants.GetBiggestPositionCount());
        _myPlayers.ReloadData();
    }
}
```